# How do I stub Google Oauth when making requests with Cypress?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, google-oauth, stub, cypress

I'm trying to use Cypress for testing my Express, Google Oauth2, React/Redux app & have hit a problem where if I try to hit my API I get a `Status 401 - Unauthorized error`.

How do I allow Cypress to hit my API and create a new ask in my actual database with testing code like:

```
cy.request('POST', '/api/ask', example_ask);
```

Is stubbing the Google Oauth the right approach? If so how do I even do that?

Comment: This is not the answer, but are you whitelisting your cookies? I think I had a similar issue like this, but not sure. so I did not want to put this in the answer section.

Comment: i know this is pretty old question, but have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

We got around this by opening up a new tab in Cypress and manually signing into Google whenever we run our tests. Not ideal, but it works.

Comment: Can you please add bit more details to your answer?